# lost directory cannot find it with testdisk

Tags: directory, data-recovery, move

I was moving a directory on my parents computer using a teamviewer session. The session responds slow and somehow, when I was moving the directory (location:
/sdb/synchronisatie/nel/) something went wrong I guess but now the directory is gone! And I cannot find it anywhere... 
I'm sure I've used 'paste' but I think nothing happened and the directory hasn't been pasted. 
Now the directory is gone as I said and I cannot find it anymore. I tried testdisk but testdisk didn't list the directory.

The directory contains all the files from my mother so I am really hoping I can find this directory again.

What can I do?

Comment: Look in the user's `$HOME/.Trash`.

Comment: I don't see a .trash directorey in the user's $home.. (turned hidden files and directories on with Ctrl + H)

Comment: I would suspect that you inadvertently dragged it to some other directory. If you wait a day the `slocate` cron will index the files in their new location and you can do a `locate <file>` of something that was in that directory to find it.

Comment: does paste work without su rights?

Comment: No, if you don't have permissions to paste in a dir it won't work. But it will typically not cut the other end until it's been pasted, but I'd have to double check that that's a true stmt.

Comment: I 've found it. I used 'paste in this directory' without noticing the directory 'thunderbird' was selected. So it was pasted in the thunderbird directory. Changed it now and place the directory at the right location.  The suggestion from slm that I dragged it to a different directory was right...

Comment: Added it as an A, you can accept it just so everyone knows that your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you likely dragged your files into another directory. To locate them you can wait a day and there's typically a cron job that runs on most distros that does a index of the files on your system using `slocate`. Once this completes you can locate your files using the `locate` command:

```
$ locate <string>
```

Where `<string>` is either the name of the directory or a file within the directory that you accidentally dragged somewhere.